# What are the differences between using the PlayServices Api and the LocationManager? Are there other methods to get the location of an android device?

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, locationmanager, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am trying to retreive the location of the Xiami Mi 8 which uses the dual frequency GPS. I am a beginner in Android and I am wondering which service is better to use in which conditions.

I would like to retreive the x, y and z coordinates (latitude, longitude and altitude) of the android device as accurately and fast as possible.

Comment: What have you researched? Could you share those links with us? What does "x,y and z coordinates of the android device" mean? PlayServices API is not one thing, it is a bundle of APIs.

Comment: I would like to get the precise localization of the phone. I know there are different ways of getting it, with or without the Google Service and I'm not sure which is the best according to what I want.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what's best for you if you don't specify in the question? `LocationManger` is only good for getting the location a few times each hour. `FusedLocation` is for frequent location access

Comment: Indeed, I am sorry if my explanations are not perfect. In fact I'd like to get the location of the device more or less constantly. So I am guessing I should better use the FusedLocation or are there other services which lets you get the location pretty frequently too ?

Comment: [This should solve your problem](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current)

Comment: @TaseerAhmad That is totally wrong.  The LocationManager allows you to get the location as frequently as you want.  In fact FusedLocation is built on top of LocationManager.  The difference between the two is that Fused has additional software to provide AGPS funcitonality that trades off accuracy for battery usage (better battery than GPS, but less accurate, but much more accurate than network).  Also Fused requires Google Play Services to be installed on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get Location on Android using `FusedLocationProviderClient`:

### Gradle Dependency:

Add this dependency to your **app/build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies{
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
}
```

### Usage:

```
// permission check
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) return

// creating location request
val request = LocationRequest().apply {
    priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    interval = Configuration.INTERVAL_IN_MS
    fastestInterval = Configuration.FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_MS
    maxWaitTime = Configuration.MAX_WAIT_TIME_IN_MS
}

// requesting location
val mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
mFusedLocationProviderClient?.requestLocationUpdates(
request,
object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
        locationResult?.let { result ->
            if (result.lastLocation != null) {
                // here you get current location
                println("Latitude: ${result.lastLocation.latitude}")
                println("Longitude: ${result.lastLocation.longitude}")
            }
        }
    }
},
Looper.getMainLooper()
)?.addOnFailureListener {
    // something went wrong!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

welcome to Stack Overflow! For future reference, I would review this [document](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when asking questions to help the community be better able to answer your questions!

All that said, your best bet is to use the [`FusedLocationProvider`](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/) api offered through Google Play Services. As the name implies, this gives you a fused location from wireless/gps/cell signals. Hope that helps!

Comment: There's lots of tradeoffs to why you'd used Fused vs LocationManager, and just saying to used Fused without discussing the reasons why you'd use one or the other is a poor answer.